# Is importing from a directory safe in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm attempting to launch an ERC-20 token, and I am under the impression that OpenZeppelin is generally a good standard to use for this process.

One concern that I have is that people seem to importing directly from the Github, which seems like poor practice considering one can never update a smart contract. What if Github goes down, is my currency broken? What if OpenZeppelin falls into disrepair, is my currency lost forever?

I know this is standard in typical apps (importing from a link I.E. JQuery, CSS packages etc...), but if these were to go down, one could easily find a new solution...not so for smart contracts on the blockchain.

Am I wrong about this? How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One concern that I have is that people seem to importing directly from the Github, which seems like poor practice considering one can never update a smart contract. What if Github goes down, is my currency broken? What if OpenZeppelin falls into disrepair, is my currency lost forever?

This does not matter and you are making many false assumptions in your thinking.

You are going to deploy a compiled bytecode on a blockchain. It does not matter where the source code for the bytecode comes from then. Then, you can have verifiable builds for this source code on Etherscan. Etherscan only cares the source code is available, it really does not matter where did you get it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how this is different from a normal import, like say importing CSS for a project? For example if I point to a CSS link, and my internet is down, the CSS won't be rendered.

Comment: Understanding the topic needs understanding how virtual machines operate. It is a subject for a whole course, so I need to skip the topic this time.

Answer (score 0):

Read about libraries in solidity. Open Zeppelin is a common one and it's already deployed. Doubt safemath and erc20 standard will change soon. You could also launch with a proxy contract for upgrades later.

Comment: Safemath is already deprecated because Solidity 0.8.x has overflow protection: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/080-breaking-changes.html?highlight=overflow

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to proxy contracts. Had not seen these before. Gave you an upvote for it.